# git getting changes of changes after a PR is (force) updated

Tags: git

Been wanting to find a way to handle this situation. Or perhaps modify the way I work?

Upstream repo creates a PR, with a commit "A".

I port this commit A over to my repo (which is a non-trivial task) to assist with code-review etc.

If some changes are required, they will force push "B" to the PR, with slightly newer/different changes. A and B will be mostly the same.

I want to update my repo with the differences between A and B. Yes, I could start (before my A) and port "B" over yet again - but it can take hours and is tedious. I can not cherry-pick B, since I already have the changes that were in A.

Simple `git diff A B` will not work - shows changes in files outside of the changes of A and B.

The commands:

```
diff <(git show A) <(git show B)
git range-diff <A>...<B>
```

will essentially show what I want, but not in a format that can be machine-applied. (I'd rather not do it by hand - we have computers for this).

Presumably this happens frequently with PRs, so I must have just missed something obvious.

Comment: Are you working in a fork of a certain repo?  What does "port this commit" mean?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this happens frequently with pull requests. For one thing, in the git workflows I'm familiar with, porting commit A to your repository is a simple and quick thing to do. Also it would be uncommon to do a forced push to update a pull request; a simple fast-forward push would be more common. Since you say these things aren't the case for you, it sounds like you're involved in a workflow that may be significantly different, and if that's the case it might be hard to find help without describing your workflow more precisely. Maybe give us a way to set up an example.

Comment: My upstream would be "OpenZFS" for illumos, I usually cherry-pick commit "A" into my "OpenZFS" for osx.  Hence the need to port the commits over - sometimes they apply without changes, sometimes they require quite a big of change, which is why I would rather not start from scratch each time the PR is updated.

Comment: David: Perhaps it is "unsual" then. But in this case, they are adding "TRIM" support to upstream, which is one commit to be nice. After code-review, they update that one commit in PR with a force push. I suppose, adding commit, then squash before merge can happen, but I'd have the same problem.

Comment: Although, it appears to be how Gerrit works, and its GUI will also display what I want, I just don't see a way to get it as a patch or commit. So it can't be that unusual a way to work.